# Rotating Vector of infintesimal length paradox?

Tags: calculus, vectors, infinitesimals

Say we have an infinitesimal value ‘dx’ and assign that to a component of some vector (let’s use a 2D vector for simplicity) ‘v = [dx, 0]’

Now let’s rotate that vector on the xy plane by anything not a multiple of 90deg.

We have a vector with components technically less than infinitesimal?

I know anything with an infinite gets into special rules, but my lack of math knowledge made this little paradox a bit hard to munch on.

Comment: A rotation does not change the length of a vector. I don't see a paradox.

Comment: I said the components of the vector would be smaller, not the magnitude.

Comment: If we're in a setting where infinitesimals exist: An infinitesimal is not a "smallest positive number," just a positive number smaller than $1/n$ for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: Seems I have some misunderstanding of infinitesimals. I’m coming from engineering, so was taught more in the light of “smallest possible” which gave rise to the concept of impulses and what not. Is there something I should read regarding them to better understand?

Comment: More accurate for the engineering definition would be "smaller than any finite time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly infinitesimals that are larger or smaller than other infinitesimals. In fact, infinitesimals work like any other number when it comes to arithmetic. $dx$ is an infinitesimal and so is $dx/2$, and they satisfy $0 < dx/2 < dx$ as you'd expect. Infinitesimals whose ratio is non-infinitesimal are said to be of the same order. Not all infinitesimals are of the same order. $(dx)^2$ is a higher order infinitesimal than $dx$, and as you'd expect, $0 < (dx)^2 < dx$.

So here we have a vector $dx\hat{\mathbf{x}}$. We rotate it by $\theta$ and get the vector $dx\cos\theta \hat{\mathbf{x}} + dx\sin\theta\hat{\mathbf{y}}$, and its length is $\sqrt{(dx)^2\cos^2\theta+(dx^2)\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{(dx)^2} = dx$.

Incidentally, using infinitesimals instead of limits to do calculus is called non-standard analysis. Which to a physicist like me is an odd name, as we use it far more often than limits. Non-standard analysis can be put on rigorous grounds and it works about like you'd expect, though there are some subtleties to watch out for.

Comment: I’m a little at a loss why we decided infinitesimals are considered “normal” than other infinite concepts. When I was taught about them, I was under the impression we were discussing 1/infinity?

Comment: @Diniden Once you're working with infinitesimals, you also have to dispense with the notion that all infinities are the same size. $2\cdot\infty > \infty$. When you think about it this has to be true. What's the difference between $\delta(x)$ and $2\delta(x)$? They're both infinitely high, but $2\delta(x)$ is twice as infinitely high.